# HTML Script Location

Tags: javascript, html, standards

Has the standard for including scripts changed again? Last time I checked everyone suggested that developers put their scripts **just before the closing `</body>` tag**.

On the Google Analytics guide they're now saying to put the script **right after the opening `<body>` tag**.

Comment: Depends on the script. Asynchronous scripts can be placed earlier in the page without affecting load times as much.

Comment: Standards according to who? I'm sure that there's more than one organization that has a conflicting standard.

Comment: Google only advices to do that as mentioned in their guide as it's async and as it's good to load Analytics as soon as possible as you could miss page clicks if it would load a while later.

Comment: @Tophandour okay maybe I should reword `standard` into `best-practice`.

Comment: @PatrickGregorio Check here on what to do about "Best Practices" questions: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265928/is-a-best-practice-question-off-topic

Basically, they might not be on-topic here but could possibly be on Programmers SE. I'm not too clear on it, so I'm not flagging either way, but hopefully this will be of some help to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `main.js` file or whatever you call it, is usually better placed at the end of your body tag. You can also put your Google Analytics scripts at the end of the page, but I think you may miss some events at that point (when all the DOM will be ready).

Also, you can load scripts like Google Analytics passing the `async` attribute to it, ie.: `<script src="googleAnalytics.js" async></script>`. In this case, it's totally ok to have it at the beginning of your body tag as it won't hold the loading of the DOM.

edit.: checking a Google Analytics script today, I noticed this `a.async=1`, so my guess is that even if you don't pass the async parameter to the script tag, google's code will still run async.

Comment: Cool, that's nice to know. I really do remember GA suggesting that I put their script before the closing body tag but I guess people were missing some data.

Comment: I would definitely load GA before your main scripts and, if you decide to put it right after opening the body tag, I'd pass the async attribute to make sure it won't 'disturb' the loading of your page

Comment: Note taken - I'll do that for my future projects. With this one I don't have edit permissions on the GA tracking file (custom made framework) so I can't add the `async` attribute.